# R - ggplot for sorted variable

Tags: r

[image]

Dear all, apologies, I just posted a question that was too broad and I am reposting by making it specific.

I am trying to recreate this chart (attached above) in the "volatility-managed portfolios" paper in the Journal of Finance, 2017. Specifically, I have a monthly time series object m_return, and a monthly time series object m_volatility (which is the realized volatility of each month based on daily returns).

Like the first chart in the attached picture, I like to display the average return of the months for five buckets sorted by the volatility (from low volatility to high volatility). I create some sample data and use the below code to illustrate, where the code simply gave me ten bars in the X axis. My question is how could I create what I wanted using ggplot without transforming m_volatility into five states of volatility (1 to 5)? and how could I display the average of the return variable in the bar plot?

Here is my sample code that did not work

```
library(ggplot2)
m_return <- c(0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.05, 0.07)
m_volatility <- c(0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19) 
m_data <- data.frame(m_return, m_volatility)
ggplot(m_data, aes(m_volatility, m_return)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Hope the question is now good for posting.
Many thanks,
Alex

Comment: *"without transforming m_volatility into five states of volatility (1 to 5)"* If you don't want to bin volatility into 5 categories, how do you expect to be able to plot average volatility per category as in the top-left panel of the figure? If you do want to bin volatility values, how are the categories defined?

Comment: I thought that the ggplot2 package may have a function that already incorporates this type of functionality as this kind of sorts is very commonly used in finance. But I was wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create 5 groups and you can use `cut` to do that.

```
library(ggplot2)

m <- data.frame(m_volatility, m_return, 
  volatility_group = cut(m_volatility, 5, lab = c("Low vol", 2, 3, 4, "High vol")))
m5 <- aggregate(m_return ~ volatility_group, m, mean)

ggplot(m5, aes(volatility_group, m_return)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("Volatility") +
  ylab("Return")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much G. Grothendieck. This is really appreciated!

Comment: I implemented the code as advised by G. Grothendieck. The slight difference from what I needed is that the cut function divides the monthly observations of volatility into buckets by equal intervals, not by equal number of observations (which was what I needed). For instance, the current Low Vol bucket has way more than 20% of the number of monthly observations, due to the volatility tends to cluster around lower values, where the High Vol bucket has very few observations. I am trying to figure out how I could modify the code, but if anyone has any thoughts I will really appreciate it

Comment: I changed the "breaks = 5" in the cut function to "breaks = quantile(m_volatility, probs=seq(0, 1, by=0.2))", and it produces what I needed now. Thanks all